# Create image File in JavaScript with a local path

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a local image, I work with Symfony so the path of image is

```
{{ asset('/ML_python/STARE/000_test_123.png') }}
```

and I want information about the image like a basic input file

```
<input type="file" class="item-img file center-block" name="file_photo"/>
```

The basic way to load this image with input file is

```
var files = $('#item-img')[0].files;
```

I cant change the value of input type="file" to put my image. How can I load my image to operate with this method

```
function readFile(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    $('.upload-demo').addClass('ready');
    $('#cropImagePop').modal('show');
    rawImg = e.target.result;
    }
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  } else {
    swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the Filupload_pyeReader API");
  }
}
```

I did this because, I convert DICOM file in PNG image and at the end of the script for converting (in success ajax request) I want use croppie: see example here :
https://codepen.io/masudrana2779/pen/wvgZExz

So i want load my image in order to crop my image with croppie function
https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/croppie.js

Thanks

I try to create a new File() but it doesnt work I try also :

```
$file = file_get_contents("{{ asset('/ML_python/STARE/000_test_123.png') }}", true);
```

According to the Github I try :

```
                success: function(response) {
                var basic = $('#demo-basic').croppie({
                    viewport: {
                        width: 150,
                        height: 200
                    }
                });
                basic.croppie('bind', {
                    url: "{{ asset('/ML_python/STARE/000_test_123.png') }}",
                    points: [77, 469, 280, 739]
                });
                // on button click
                basic.croppie('result', 'html').then(function(html) {
                    // html is div (overflow hidden)
                    // with img positioned inside.
                });
            }
```

```
I get this error 

> croppie.js:1543 Uncaught Error: Croppie: Can't initialize croppie more than once
var basic = $('#demo-basic').croppie({
```

Comment: _"and I want information about the image like a basic input file"_ - what "information"? Be a bit more specific, please. I currently can't tell what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: I editing my post :)

Comment: So then why don't you use the cropping library with an existing image, as the basic examples under https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/ already show?

Comment: I went to try but I get error see edit post

Comment: When does this occur, when that `success` function executes a second time? Then you will have to check if you already created a croppie instance on the target element - and then either re-use the existing one (if that makes sense), or call the `destroy` method on the existing one first.